# How to rename text files according to their content?

Tags: linux, file, rename

My OS is Ubuntu; I have a directory with text files; each file includes a line with unique ID

IDtag IDnumber

The line location is random inside a text file, however, it is easy to recognize it be simple regex

^IDtag ID[0-9]*

How to rename the files according to their IDs? I.e. each file has to obtain a new name IDnumber.txt
I can run a Linux shell script or Perl script.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this first

```
for i in a b c; do echo mv $i `egrep -m1 -e 'IDtag ID[0-9]*' $i | sed -e 's/IDtag ID//'`; done
```

If the `mv`s are correct - remove the echo bit

Comment: This is a comment for Ed Heal command:
for i in a.txt b.txt c.txt; do echo mv $i `egrep -m1 -e 'IDtag ID[0-9]*' $i | sed -e 's/IDtag ID//'`; done
it returns message like
mv a.txt <IdNumberFromA.txt>
mv b.txt <IdNumberFromB.txt>
mv a.txt <IdNumberFromC.txt>

if "echo" removed, it renames the files to their IdNumbers

Comment: I put the `echo` in so you can check first. Of course you can change a b c to *.txt - or whatever glob you want.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for the quick reply. I was googling for a half of  a day with no success trying to compose something like this. Could you recommend some time tested Linux commands tutorial/guide for beginners? I'm totally new for this environment

Comment: @Novice735 - Just read the manual page for Bash - and then f**k up a few times. You only learn from your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework.
But i would partly answer your question.
below will give the list of all command to be executed to rename the files.

```
grep ^IDtag * | awk '{split($1,a,":");print "mv",a[1], $2".txt"}'

ivory.192> grep ^IDtag * | awk '{split($1,a,":");print "mv",a[1], $2".txt"}'
mv 000001 000001.txt
mv temp2 000002.txt
ivory.193>
```

put this in a for loop and execute each and every line in a shell script.

additionally to have a track you can redirect the output to a file and give the file execute permissions and execute it as a script.this will do your purpose additionally you also have the list of files which were renamed.

Comment: Thanks Rahul! your commands worked on my computer, and the idea to redirect output for tracking is useful.  <br/> Just in case, the  story is - I got big files someone created by merging many individual files, and now I want to restore them. The command csplit helped me to restore the files, not filenames.